# C# connecting to MySQL -get DB user rights?

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

I am using System.data.odbc to communicate with my MySQL db. When logged, I would need to know whather the user is admin or not, just to know the rights. Is there any way how to retrieve rights of currently logged user?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [SHOW command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html) to retrieve the current user's grants:

```
SHOW GRANTS
```

If you don't have the SELECT privilege, SHOW GRANTS will throw an error :)

There's also an [INFORMATION_SCHEMA table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-privileges-table.html) you can select from:

```
select * from information_schema.user_privileges
```

Comment: Thanks,also select * from information_schema.user_privileges WHERE name='username'? Or ID? I dont know the structure of these table :)

Comment: The field that contains the username is [grantee].  On my server, it contains values like 'andomar'@'%'

Comment: One more thing please :)
I have tried SHOW GRANTS, but the result is like:
"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*A02AA727CF2E8C5E6F07A382910C4028D65A053A' WITH GRANT OPTION"

How can I compare if its admin or not? I expected number :(

Comment: It depends on what you mean by admin.  But if the result of "SHOW GRANTS" contains "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO ", you are logged in on a powerful account.